# Is it possible to run the main QT program on a thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt

I have a simple QT object. When I execute the code below the control is transfer to the QT object, but I would like to make the QT part work like a thread.

```
int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
    gui *GUI;
    //// before call 

    QApplication app(argc,args);
    GUI = new gui();    
    GUI->show();

////i want to be able to do stuff here in parallel with the QT code.
// If I spawn a thead here or give a simple printf statement here
// or before call it executes only after GUI exits

return app.exec();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you not only create the thread but actually start it. Also, a `printf()` statement will execute before the GUI shows unless you forgot to terminate the string with a newline (`\n`).